Configure IBMMQ JNDI context with JMS in Spring Boot
I'm working with a legacy code, and I'm trying to connect my JMS producer with my local IBM MQ server
MQSeries container
# docker-compose.yml

version: '2'
services:
  mqseries:
    image: ibmcom/mq:9.2.1.0-r1
    ports:
      - "1414:1414"
      - "9443:9443"
    hostname: mq
    environment:
      - LICENSE=accept
      - MQ_QMGR_NAME=QM1
    container_name: mqserver
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    restart: always

I was able to access the console-ui in https://localhost:9443/ibmmq/console
Now I want to setup the JNDI ConnectionFactory
    public void setupLocalJNDIConnectionFactory(String connectionFactoryJndiName)
            throws JMSProducerException {
    
        try {
            connectionFactory = ServiceLocator.getJmsConnectionFactory(connectionFactoryJndiName);
        } catch (ServiceLocatorException ex) {
            throw new JMSProducerException(ex);
        }
    }

I have this in the ServiceLocator
    public static ConnectionFactory getJmsConnectionFactory(Context ctx, String jmsConnectionFactoryJndiName) {
        ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory = null;
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext()
        try {
            
            jmsConnectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(jmsConnectionFactoryJndiName);
        } catch (CException cce) {

        }

        return jmsConnectionFactory;
    }

Error
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or in an application resource file: java.naming.factory.initial



Are you using the mq-jms-spring-boot-starter? - https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring

no! it's an old application, I'm trying to use the same method ! obviously I'm struggling to

Take a look at docs for spring JNDI for JMS for inspiration or second part of Develop MQ JMS Spring apps tutorial which makes use of Sample code for JMS SpringBoot-MVC
